# Using this value "2016-05-12 21:51:13 -0500" in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How do I work with a Date Time -0500 value?

I have a sheet that has a value that looks like this:

```
2016-05-12 21:51:13 -0500
```

I want to be about to use it.

I want to filter all records that are greater than

```
2016-05-12 00:00:01 -0500
```

But I do not know how to work with this value.

Comment: Is it always `-0500`?  I assume this is the local timezone adjustment off Greenwich time?

Comment: Better question is it stored as a string which I am guessing it is.  -ISTEXT(A1) where A1 is your time.  If the two methods below do not work for you its has to do with system date settings not matching up. but that can be dealt with.  Scott's question about -0500 is very important.  This is the amount of time you need to shift your timestamp by to get it in local time,  If all time stamps are -0500 we can pretty much ignore it as all time is shifted the same amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=--LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-5)
```

Then format it like this

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss -\0\5\0\0
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then you can copy and paste the values and formatting where you want it

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the data into Excel date/times.  With data in **A1** in **B1** enter:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))+TIME(MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,15,2),MID(A1,18,2))
```

and format to display both date and time:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's presume for a moment that for some unknown reason Excel could not identify your string as a valid date time. You can always go back to basics and break your string down into its components. Let's start off and assume that your date time and offset string are in cell A1.

#### Step 1) Strip out the year

```
=left(A1,4)
```

#### Step 2) Strip out the month

```
=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)-FIND("-",A1)-1)
```

That bad boy of a formula looks for the first - and the second - and based on that information finds the starting position to start pulling characters from and figures out how many characters to pull.

In your case we could have set it to pull two characters and had it start at character six as there is no variation to your date format. However, in a generic sense where there are not always leading zeros in the month, or sometimes you were flipping between four characters for the year and two characters for the year, the above would still work.

I am also assuming that month is the middle value (05) and you are not talking about December 5th here.

#### Step 3) Pull out the day

We could have used a similar approach using `mid` here, and again we could have hard coded it (wait, I did hard code two character return). Instead for a little flavour I used a right left sequence.

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),2)
```

#### Step 4) Pull out the time

Now you could go through the whole process and pull out hours, minutes and seconds, but Excel is usually pretty good at recognizing a time format as there is not much variation to it. Also this gives an opportunity to see a new formula for dealing with string manipulation.

Now since your time format was constant, I got a little lazy knowing that your time was always going to be eight characters long since your format always has a leading zero. As such, I used the following:

```
=TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,8))
```

Basically, I grabbed the whole time, HH:mm:ss, and dumped it into timevalue (note there is also a datevalue). Timevalue will attempt to convert a string in time format to Excel time format as a decimal value.

Now as previously noted, if all those times are all stamped with the same -0500, just ignore it.

To get all that date and time converted into a single cell we would take each of the date parts and drop them into the DATE function and then add the time component on. In Excel speak that looks like:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)-FIND("-",A1)-1),RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),2))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,8))
```

Now if you want that to display with the -0500, look at [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221103/using-this-value-2016-05-12-215113-0500-in-excel/37221362#37221362) for formatting. If you want to convert the time to local time and get rid of the -0500 then you would need to add -5 hours to the above formula which would look something like:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)-FIND("-",A1)-1),RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),2))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,8))+time(-5,0,0)
```

And if we were not so lazy and did not want to hard code the time, it would look more like:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)-FIND("-",A1)-1),RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),2))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,8))+TIME(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,4),2),RIGHT(A1,2),0)*IF(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,5),1)="-",-1,1)
```